# Application not finding MQ 9.3 Header Files

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I am developing a MQ Client application in C++ and am getting a compilation error.

I think it relates to the location of the MQ client header files: I have installed MQSeriesSDK 9.3 rpm on Linux but cannot find the header files anywhere.

Comment: Usually `/opt/mqm/inc` if you installed in the standard location.

Comment: You can also use `rpm -ql RPMName` to list all files instants by that rpm.

Comment: This question is about the location of the IBM MQ C++ header files,  why is that considered "not about programming"?

Comment: Rework the question to "Why am I getting this compilation error", showing relevant code, and the compilation error message thrown. JoshMc's comment can then become the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed in the standard location they will be located in `/opt/mqm/inc`.